# Parsing links in include parameter text

Tags: jekyll

My Jekyll template has a simple alert include:

```
<div{% if include.style %} class="uk-alert-{{ include.style }}"{% endif %} data-uk-alert>
    <p>{{ include.text | markdownify }}</p>
</div>
```

I am trying to do something like this:

```
{% include alert.html style="warning" text="This article is for Administrators and other Roles. Learn more about [permissions]({% link _docs/permissions.md %}) and [roles]({% link _docs/roles.md %})." %}
```

The issue is the output is not parsed by markdown and I get the raw text:

```
This article is for Administrators and other Roles. Learn more about [permissions](/support/docs/permissions/) and [roles](/support/docs/roles/).
```

Tried adding this:

```
<div{% if include.style %} class="uk-alert-{{ include.style }}"{% endif %} data-uk-alert>
    <p>{{ include.text | markdownify }}</p>
</div>
```

This sort of works but I get extra `<p></p>` before and after the markdown text and it adds padding.

So far this is what I have working with a capture:

```
{% capture alert_text %}This article is for Administrators and other Roles. Learn more about <a href="{% link _docs/permissions.md %}">permissions</a> and <a href="{% link _docs/roles.md %}">roles</a>.{% endcapture %}
{% include alert.html style="warning" text=alert_text %}
```

Can I just just have the link generated inline direct or somehow eliminate the extra paragraph tags?

Answer (score 1):

A single line of markdown is considered a paragraph, which is why it's being wrapped in those tags. I'd keep the capture to render out the liquid `link` tags, and just remove the `p` tags in the include:

```
<div{% if include.style %} class="uk-alert-{{ include.style }}"{% endif %} data-uk-alert>
  {{ include.text | markdownify }}
</div>
```

If you're seeing the `p` tags added before or after, it's because an opening `p` tag implies the close of the previous one. If you're still having issues with whitespace on each end of your text, you could `strip` it before `markdownify` to be sure:

```
{{ include.text | strip | markdownify }}
```